# React State update not happening on first click?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I am trying to update the state and filter the array data when I press the search button. However the the data gets filtered only on the second click, the first click returns undefined or does not update the state, but clicking it again the functionality works and state is updated?

```
const data = [
  {
    ID: '12345',
    name: 'John',
    age: '20',
  },
  {
    ID: '67890',
    name: 'Mike',
    age: '21',
  },
];

const SearchOne = props => {
  const [id, setId] = useState('');
  const [click, setClick] = useState(0);
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState();

  const searchit = enteredid => {
    console.log(enteredid, 'enteredid'),
      setFilteredData(data.filter(datasearch => datasearch.ID === enteredid));
    console.log(filteredData, 'fd');
    setClick(prevState => prevState + 1);
    console.log('click', click);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.mainarea}>
        <View style={styles.innerview}>
          <TextInput
            value={id}
            onChangeText={text => {
              setId(text);
            }}
            placeholder="Enter Search ID here"
          />
          <Button
            title="search"
            onPress={() => {
              searchit(id);
            }}
          />
        </View>
        {filteredData && <Text> Filtered Data: {filteredData[0].name}</Text>}
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Are you saying this just because it doesn't log what you expect, or because the view doesn't update?

Comment: @Adam when I click the search button first time, the function should run and sort the data but it does not do that  console.log(filteredData, 'fd'); return undefined but as soon as I click the search button the filter logic works and console.log(filteredData, 'fd') prints the filter data. why it is not filtering the data on the first time?

Comment: You didn't answer my question - forgetting about the console.log's, is the view updating correctly?

Comment: @Adam yes the view is getting updated on the first click itself. But in my real project (which I am not showing here, this is just mimic of that) I have the same condition as here but it shows error in there.

Comment: Then you should show the real problem you are trying to fix. `setState` is `asynchronous` - check the dupe. I was about to mark this as a dupe for the same question, but figured I'd ask first. If you're still having problems in your real project, open a new question with your real problem.

Comment: @Adam dupe is class component and this functional but I thought execution pattern would be different

Comment: It is not different.